# How to check a file is open or not in FileHelper

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filehelpers

I am using [FileHelper](http://www.filehelpers.com/) for exporting the data to csv for my `C#` project.  I am facing an `exception`

> *"The process cannot access the file"*

the reason is the file is already opened.  Is there any option to check whether the file is already opened or not.

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ClassName));
engine.WriteFile("file.csv", obj);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Janes Abou Chleih: I'm trying to find a way using FileHelper library.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Thanks for your edits.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. 
When you catch the exception, don't you automatically know that the file is in use?
something like: `using(FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ClassName))){
try{
engine.WriteFile("file.csv", obj);
}catch{
//File is in use
}
}`

Comment: You should just catch the exception and respond appropriately. Checking if a file is in use before opening it can lead to a race condition because some other process could open it inbetween you checking if it's open and you trying to open it, so you'd still need to deal with potential exceptions anyway.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih,@MatthewWatson: Thanks.  But I thought that FileHelpers has some options to handle this exception.